# Cannot boot 13.10 on 2013 Mac Mini

Tags: boot, live-usb, mac, apple

Since the update to OS X Mavericks seems to have corrupted my grub on my Linux partition, I now would like to boot into a LiveCD and restore grub again.

Sadly using the 13.10 Mac Desktop iso, I get a USB stick, which gets correctly found by the Mac (as "Windows"), but when trying to boot I only get

```
Boot error
```

The same is true for a 13.04 Mac iso.
Has anyone successfully booted this LiveCD on a recent Mac(Mini)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like USB sticks only work for Mac when created via [Mac OSX tools](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

Neither *unetbootin* nor *usb-creator-gtk* produced bootable sticks.